# How can I replace the first element of each line in a list in PYTHON?

Tags: python, replace

I'm a little beginner, 
 i have a list  and I need to change the first ";" with "\n[" , and the third ";" with "]" 
i have this:

```
print(lista)

>A0A024;167;188;22;DiPPE
>A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC
>A0AV6;38;58;21;Diwc
>A0AV7;408;432;25;Diwc
```

i try:

```
lista1=str(lista).replace(";","\n[",1)
```

but only replace the first in the list:

```
>A0A024
[167;188;22;DiPPE
>A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC
>A0AV6;38;58;21;DiwC
>A0AV7;408;432;25;DiwC
```

need to be:

```
>A0A024
[167;188]22;DiPPE
>A0AV
[1;25]25;DiWC
>A0AV6
[38;58]21;DiwC
>A0AV7
[408;432]25;DiwC
```

Comment: Do not call your variables `list,set,dict,tuple.avg,min,max,...` you are shadowing the inbuilt functions

Answer (score 2):

**Create the data**

```
parts = """A0A024;167;188;22;DiPPE
A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC
A0AV6;38;58;21;Diwc
A0AV7;408;432;25;Diwc""".split("\n")
```

**Go over the data of lines, split at `;` and recombine as wanted:**

```
for idx,line in enumerate(parts):
    # make it a list without any ;
    pp = line.split(";")
    # make it a string and reassign into parts
    parts[idx]= pp[0] + "\n[" + pp[1] + ";" + pp[2] + "]" + ";".join(pp[3:])

print(parts)

for p in parts:
    print(p)
```

**Output:**

```
# data as list  
['A0A024\n[167;188]22;DiPPE', 'A0AV\n[1;25]25;DiWC', 
 'A0AV6\n[38;58]21;Diwc', 'A0AV7\n[408;432]25;Diwc']

# data linewise 
A0A024
[167;188]22;DiPPE
A0AV
[1;25]25;DiWC
A0AV6
[38;58]21;Diwc
A0AV7
[408;432]25;Diwc
```

Comment: I guess the > at the stat of your data is leftover from your first editing tries when you had it in citations...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

- The first replace replaces all `';'` to `']'`.
- The second replaces the 3 first `']'` to `';'`.
- And the last one replaces the first `';'` to `'\n['`.

```
data = [">A0A024;167;188;22;DiPPE",
        ">A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC",
        ">A0AV6;38;58;21;Diwc",
        ">A0AV7;408;432;25;Diwc"]

res = [s.replace(';', ']').replace(']', ';', 3). replace(';', '\n[', 1) for s in data]

for s in res:
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each line on `;` and create a new line by formatting the parts:

```
def format_line(line):
    return '{0}\n[{1};{2}]{3};{4}'.format(*line.split(';'))
```

Using this function, you can do:

```
data = """A0A024;167;188;22;DiPPE
A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC
A0AV6;38;58;21;Diwc
A0AV7;408;432;25;Diwc"""

lines = data.split('\n')
out = '\n'.join([format_line(line) for line in lines])
```

Output:

```
print(out)

A0A024
[167;188]22;DiPPE
A0AV
[1;25]25;DiWC
A0AV6
[38;58]21;Diwc
A0AV7
[408;432]25;Diwc
```

Answer (score 0):

here a solution with re

```
import re

# my guess on how lista looks like, it is more useful to show the actual variable, than the output btw.
lista = ">A0A024;167;188;22;DiPPE\n>A0AV;1;25;25;DiWC\n>A0AV6;38;58;21;Diwc\n>A0AV7;408;432;25;Diwc"

lista = lista.split("\n")
lista1 = []
for elem in lista:
    lista1.append(re.sub(r'(.+?);(.+?;.+?);', r'\1\n[\2]', elem))

print(*lista1, sep='\n')
```

for the first `elem` in the list `r'(.+?);(.+?;.+?);'` will match `>A0A024;167;188;`, and it will substitute each of the 2 groups (`>A0A024`, and `167;188`) in the match with this pattern `r'\1\n[\2]'`.